# How can I debug cache tags not invalidated as expected?

Tags: caching, 9

Up unto last week my Drupal site and varnish_purge worked together fine with Varnish. After updating the modules to the latest versions, cache tag invalidation seemed to stop. Nothing else really changed in the meantime.
In /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log I get messages like the following.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2021:09:04:13 +0100] "BAN http://127.0.0.1:6081/ HTTP/1.1" 200 254 "-" "varnish_purger module for Drupal 8."
```

In the syslog there are no messages from Varnish or Drupal.

After changing something on a page, `drush p:queue-work` should give a notice like the following.

> Processed 5 objects...

It instead shows the following.

> The queue is empty or has only locked items!

**How should I debug this?**

**Edit**
I tested on an old site when the problem started, it looked like that, as soon as module "typed data" was updated, the problem started.

What I tried without solving the problem:

- reinstall typed data
- reinstall purge modules
- reinstall Varnish
- installed another module for purging (advanced_varnish)
- removed all modules
- removed the vendor folder and composer.lock file, cleaned the composer cache and did a composer install
- used a views block in the layout builder to show the text
- removed everything from the layout in the layout builder but the body text, then when placing a certain views block, the problem starts. But, when doing that in a clean install, the problem doesn't appear.
- build a clean install trying to introduce the problem
- increase nginx body buffer size

**Edit**: to get an idea of the installed modules, this is the composer.json:

```
{
"name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "role": ""
    }
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "slick/slick",
            "version": "v1.8.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/archive/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "bower-asset/blazy": "^1.8",
    "bower-asset/jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1",
    "bower-asset/jquery.easing": "^1.3",
    "bower-asset/jquery.pause": "^0.1",
    "bower-asset/lazysizes": "^5.1",
    "bower-asset/slick-carousel": "^1.8",
    "composer/installers": "^1.7",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
    "drupal/antibot": "^1.4",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^5.0@beta",
    "drupal/bg_image_formatter": "^1.11",
    "drupal/blazy": "^2.4",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.20",
    "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.0",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.6",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.0",
    "drupal/email_registration": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.2",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
    "drupal/image_effects": "^3.1",
    "drupal/image_style_warmer": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.3",
    "drupal/imagemagick": "^3.3",
    "drupal/imagick": "^1.5",
    "drupal/imce": "^2.3",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^1.2",
    "drupal/layout_builder_styles": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/lazy": "^3.4",
    "drupal/mautic": "^1.1",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.0",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.10",
    "drupal/migrate_file": "^2.0",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^5.1",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^5.0",
    "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.4",
    "drupal/poll": "^1.4",
    "drupal/publication_date": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/purge_purger_http": "^1.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.4",
    "drupal/robots_noindex_nofollow": "2.0.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/rules": "3.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/scheduler": "^1.1",
    "drupal/scroll_progress": "9.1.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/search_autocomplete": "^2.0",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^4.1",
    "drupal/slick": "^2.3",
    "drupal/slick_extras": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/slick_views": "^2.4",
    "drupal/social_media": "^1.9@RC",
    "drupal/svg_image": "^1.9",
    "drupal/taxonomy_menu": "3.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/twitter_block": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@dev",
    "drupal/varnish_purge": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.6",
    "drush/drush": "^10.3",
    "league/csv": "^9.1@dev",
    "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "fxp-asset": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "web/libraries",
            "bower-asset-library": "web/libraries"
        }
    },
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true,
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ],
    "files": ["load.environment.php"]
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "installer-types": ["bower-asset", "npm-asset"],
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patchLevel": {
        "drupal/core": "-p2"
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library", "type:bower-asset", "type:npm-asset"],
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/modules/{$name}": ["type:unity-module"],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "initial": {
            ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
            ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
        }
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
        ]
    },
    "patches": {
        "drupal/content_sync": {
            "repareer": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-05-06/content_sync-entity_manager_refs.patch"
        },
        "drupal/search_autocomplete": {
            "fix Uncaught TypeError: value.autocomplete is not a function": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-06-24/value-autocomplete-not-function-3220334-3.patch"
        }
    },
    "enable-patching": true
}
```

}

Comment: What are the precise version changes that broke the feature?

Comment: If a clean install helps, I would try to reset the purge modules settings, saving that config newly may fix your problems.

For debugging I can recommend xdebug - the question is where to set the breakpoints ;)

Comment: thanks remy, I already deinstalled and reinstalled Varnish and purge modules, and tried all kind of new settings (but, then again: the old settings were fine). Because I don't have experience with debugging Drupal modules themselves, xdebug would be a step too far.

Comment: @cilefen I made an edit in the question about when the site broke

Comment: Which purge plugins are enabled? Do you have the core cache tags queuer enabled? Do you have a queue processor enabled?

Comment: The purge module is enabled and I tried varnish_purge, later advanced-varnish. Yes, together with  core cache tags queuer enabled, and queue processors.